# Just starting out with Phonegap and having trouble with XCode

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to run the 'hello world' example from the Phonegap documentation here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

but am already having trouble.

This is my first attempt at working with Xcode.

When I go to build and run the test app, I don't have the option to run the 5.1 simulator, just 4.3. And when I do compile, I'm getting 400+ errors.

I can't seem to find any documentation indicating what I might be doing wrong.

I'm running 10.8, Phonegap 2.2.0, and XCode 4.5.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitly see the iOS 6.0 simulators. Try going to the "Preferences" and select the "Downloads" tab. Can you download/update the latest iOS Libraries?

If not, I suggest a fresh Xcode install.

Comment: Thanks! Had to break out the command line to completely remove everything. http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something went wrong with your Xcode / iOS sdk setup - With a new install you should only see the 6.0 simulator - older ones are available as an additional download.